# why does it take so long for selenium grid2 rc node to register with hub?

Tags: webdriver, selenium-grid

I have selenium grid 2 hub running on one server.

I start up another selenium grid 2 webdriver node on another server.

It takes about 4 minutes of refreshing in my browser at http://remotehub.com:4444/grid/console until I can finally see the normal hub console displaying the browser icons.

anyway to speed this up? what is the reason that it's taking so long?

does it have to do anything with max number of instances on the rc node? How can I change this to run 25 instances on a rc node? does each browser instance require it's own xvfb display number or can RC handle as much as memory and cpu allows under a single xvfb display?

Comment: Please provide more details about your configuration.  A good starter is which version of Selenium Grid 2 you're actually using.  If you think it's a bug, please file an issue in the Selenium issue tracker.

Comment: Oh, and you'll probably have better luck getting answers to all the questions in the last paragraph by splitting them out into separate questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you start the server and client on the same machine, do you have the same problem?
Four minute seems like an unreasonable amount of time for the console to display. I wonder if something is mis-configured on the remote site or they are experiencing other performance-hindering problems.

I'm starting my server like this:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.0rc2.jar -role hub
```

You can change the max number of instances on a particular node (client) by starting it up like this (note the **maxInstance** sub-parameter within the **-browser** parameter).

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.0rc2.jar -role webdriver -hub http://127.0.0.1:4444/grid/register -port 5556 -browser browserName=firefox,version=3.6,platform=windows,maxInstances=2 -browser "browserName=internet explorer,version=8,platform=windows,maxInstances=2"
```

This starts a node that has 2 Firefox and 2 IE browsers ready to receive tests, up to a maximum of five tests.

Comment: this can also be caused by the inability to connect to the remote node.  see this post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21083492/selenium-grid-hub-operation-timed-out

Answer (score 0):

If you are running selenium node on Linux in a virtual machine or headless server, this probably is because your VM/server does not have enough entropy .

To resolve this problem, simply install `haveged` (or other similar things).

To install it on CentOS 7, you need have EPEL enabled, then run:

```
yum install haveged
systemctl enable haveged
systemctl start haveged
```

For other Linux distributions, see: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-additional-entropy-for-cloud-servers-using-haveged