# Selenium Grid Hub Operation timed out

Tags: windows, macos, selenium

I am trying to run Behat Tests on the Windows 7 VM node installed using my Mountain Lion Mac computer as hub.

I am using the latest seleniun (2.39.0)

I run the following command on the node VM

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar -role node -hub http://10.0.2.2:4444/grid/register -browser "browserName=internet explorer,version=8,maxinstances=1" -Dwebdriver.ie.driver="D:\tools\IEDriverServer.exe"
```

This sends the request to the hub machine, and it "seems" as though the hub has received this, this is because when I access localhost:4444/grid/console on the hub machine it shows the registered node (see screenshot below)

[image]

But the error comes when the hub tries to send a request to the node and it can't because the connection is refused. But I have disabled the windows firewall so this connection should go through right?

[image]

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Download this book, it will help you to setup Grid
http://www.packtpub.com/sites/default/files/downloads/Distributed_Testing_with_Selenium_Grid.pdf

Comment: Yeah I followed this but I still had the same problem. I might try it out with later version of selenium and see how it goes.

Answer (score 3):

So, I figured out my problem and it was nothing to do with the commands posted here. I did not give enough network permissions to my VM to allow the connection. Easiest solution was to make the VM act as a seperate computer on the network, which solved all the problems :).

Comment: had the same problem, and it was the windows firewall

Comment: After I switched the VirtualBox network interface from NAT to Bridge it worked.